# About Android can't load json file in Application.persistentDataPath

Tags: android, json, unity-game-engine

I put json file in Application.persistentDataPath,then It's can load and work on PC.

But It can't work in Android ,I'm stuck for a long time.

I found the many way , but no one can fix it .

please help me , thank you!

```
using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using UnityEngine;
using System.IO;




public class QuizCon : MonoBehaviour
{
 public RoundData[] allRoundData;
 private string gameDataFileName = "quiz.json";


 private void Start()
 {

     DontDestroyOnLoad(gameObject);
     LoadGameData();

 }

public RoundData GetCurrectRoundData()
 {
     return allRoundData[0];
 }

private void LoadGameData()
 {
     string filePath = Path.Combine(Application.persistentDataPath, gameDataFileName);
     if(File.Exists(filePath))
     {
         string dataJson = File.ReadAllText(filePath);
         GameData loadedData = JsonUtility.FromJson<GameData>(dataJson);

         allRoundData = loadedData.allRoundData;
     }
     else
     {
         Debug.LogError("Cannot load game data!");
     }
 }
```

Answer (score 0):

Try writing the file to External (SDCard) instead of Internal.

You can change this under PlayerSettings -> Android

[image: External SD Card Setting]

Comment: I solve the problem . I put the file in StreamingAssets ,and use UnityWebRequest to get the file. Thank you !